# Getting two unknown error while trying to upload my app to Heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, pip

I've been the past 2 hours trying to deploy my app to Heroku but i'm getting a lot of errors. I have python 3.8.2 installed. Thanks in advance

```
remote:          Collecting xattr==0.6.4
remote:          Downloading xattr-0.6.4.tar.gz (15 kB)

ERROR:           Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zvu2zply/xattr/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zvu2zply/xattr/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-zvu2zply/xattr/pip-egg-info
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-zvu2zply/xattr/
remote:            Complete output (8 lines):
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-zvu2zply/xattr/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:                import ez_setup
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-zvu2zply/xattr/ez_setup.py", line 106
remote:                except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
remote:                                                    ^
remote:            SyntaxError: invalid syntax
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python
```

Comment: How could I change that? @skaul05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SynaxError` at `except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:` means the code is intended for Python 2 but you're executing it with Python 3.

[`xattr` 0.6.4](https://pypi.org/project/xattr/0.6.4/) was released in 2012. It's simply too old, it only supports Python 2.

So either use Python 2 for you code or upgrade `xattr` to a [later version](https://pypi.org/project/xattr/#history).